# get variable value from a php class

Tags: php, variables, get

In this function i am getting the value of **"apartmentId"**

```
function aptAction(){
$user->.......
.......
$apartmentId = $user->getApartments()->get(0)->getId();
}
```

Now i have another function where i want to get this variable value, so i write like so ---

```
$val = $this->aptAction()->apartmentId;
```

which is wrong i know.

If i write like so ---

```
$val = $this->aptAction();
```

it will return a lot's of value which i do not need, i need only a selected variable value, how i can do that. can anyone help me to fix this.

Comment: Learn how to pass and use parameters within function

Comment: just make a `getApartmentIdAction()` or something like that...

Comment: use `return $apartmentId `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `$val = $this->aptAction();` isn't going to work as currently, `aptAction()` doesn't actually return anything.

In order to use it in this way you need to `return` a value out of it like this.

```
function aptAction(){
    //$user->.......
    //.......

    return $user->getApartments()->get(0)->getId();
}
```

now when you call `$val = $this->aptAction();` you will get the value you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Build a array what values you want, Using below conversion make object and return the object.

```
    function aptAction() { $array = array(
        'apartmentId' => $user->getApartments()->get(0)->getId(), 
        'id' =>200
        );
    $object = json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE);
    return $object;
}
```

..
.
$this->aptAction()->apartmentId;